# Got cluster not defined when trying to run cluster.vq.vq() in Scipy lib

Tags: scipy

I am trying to learn anomaly detection by following :
https://github.com/sayakpaul/FloydHub-Anomaly-Detection-Blog/blob/master/FloydHub%20Anomaly%20Detection%20Blog.ipynb

I installed necessary libraries using:
python -m pip install --user numpy scipy matplotlib ipython jupyter pandas sympy nose

cluster.vq.vq() is included in these libraries. However i am getting name error :
NameError: name 'cluster' is not defined

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Now i solved my own question,

You just need to import:
from scipy.cluster.vq import vq

and instead of  cluster.vq.vq(),  vq() is enough